# How to set up a FTP Server for multiple users with their separate directories?

Tags: ftp

I have to set up a FTP server so that different people can log in to the server using a username and a password.

Also, each user

- Should have their own directories
- Other user's directories should be inaccessible to them
- Users should have the capability to
  upload, download and delete content
  in their directory using something like FileZilla

Also, the Admin should be able to download/remove any file from any of the user's directories.

How do I make this possible? I have zero idea about FTP and such, so please take that into consideration as well as you solve my problem. Thanks in advance :)

**Update:** Also idea on obtaining a free ftp address? Is it possible to use dyndns.com to track the dynamic IP on this computer with port-forwarding to create a ftp address?

**Update 2:** Do I need to set up an Apache server on the local machine that I install FileZilla as well? If so how do I go about it?

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us what FTP server platform you plan to use.

Comment: FTP server platform? I have no idea what that means, so you see how blind I am. Need something that is free.

Comment: I mean what type of server, Linux/Unix or Windows? Are you planning on using third party FTP server software, such as Filezilla?

Comment: Hopefully something that runs on Windows Vista or Windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.04. And yes FileZilla would be good because it's GUI.

Comment: Despite all of the fancy-schmancy FTP software available these days, I’m still using a good-old copy of WAR-FTPD 1.67-05. It was *quite* easy to set up with various useful and powerful settings (multiple users, logins, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using FileZilla server version with out issue for the last couple of years, i have also used bullet proof ftp as well. Filezilla seems to do the job equally as well so have stuck with that.

If it was me i would down load the software from sourceforge and install on the box which is going to act as your FTP server. I would then test it on your local area network before figuring out all the IP mapping and firewall options.

If you are used to windows software it is fairly straight forward to get started with and creating user accounts and setting permissions is straight forward as well. If you create an ftp directory somewhere on your hard drive and then sub-folders within that for each user when creating the accounts you can just give the user access to that folder. It also means your super user account can have full control form the level above to add / remove files as needed.

You might also want to think about security as well as FTP is targeted quiet often, i typically silently banner IP addresses after a number of failed attempts, make sure i update the welcome message to remove software versions etc, and lock the admin interface down to an internal IP address range.

[Filezilla homepage](http://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: Thanks :) Very nice answer :) will try it out and post back here :)

Answer (score 1):

For $99 you can get a license of [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) that can be configured to only allow FTP into the users home directory.   Also, if the remote server is a Windows server edition (not home or professional), then you get multiple separate terminal service sessions.   A lot for $100.

Of course, if you need something totall free, get FileZilla server and you can manually map each account to its own Windows directory.  A bit more configuration but its free.

Comment: I like the FileZilla Server+Client idea. Is there some step-by-step guide with screenshots preferably to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the application CrushFTP for sveral years and it ws inexpensive and very feature rich.  Support is excellemnt and all suers need is a web browser to upload or download.  It supports secure transfers and has extensive reporting and alerting.  Great features to protect against various attacks.  It was easy to set up and users like all the features and security. Supports a number of platforms and uses few resourses.

[CrushFTP Website](http://www.crushftp.com)

Comment: Seems like the best option. The "web interface" it provides is a nice feature that other FTP servers dont have.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows platform, try using this ftp server: [Cerberus FTP Server](http://www.cerberusftp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, **BulletProof FTP Server** is the one that I have been using since 2003 and with no issues at all, easy to install, easy to manage, with a few useful features like the hit-o-meter, groups or per user configuration, and the very best for me is that I can make this server perform a sound when a specific event occurs.

http://www.bpftp.com/

The DDNS can be achieved by using the appropriate modem/router config with DynDNS, but my favorite is No-IP ( http://www.no-ip.com ), any of those will do the trick if you proper configure the NAT and Firewall in your Server.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[SFTPPlus Server](http://www.sftpplus.com) (FTP/FTPS/SFTP/SCP/HTTPS) is available on Windows / Linux / AIX / Solaris / HP-UX  and by default all accounts are locked (chrooted) inside their home folder.

Beside plain text configuration files it also comes with a web based administrative tools.

PS: I am one of the persons behind SFTPPlus